# What's a good, small, auto/thyristor flash? (non-TTL)

Tags: equipment-recommendation, flash

Persistently on my wish list is a small, portable, auto-mode flash.  Non-TTL is a must, as I need to use it on a bunch of different equipment.

But the vast array of flashes out there is a bit bewildering; does anyone have some recommendations?

Intended use is wide/normal lenses, mostly as direct fill.  I'll emphasize **small**; I can live without zoom, bounce, and many other things in preference of portability.

I've used:

- Vivitar 283 & 285: Just too big, really.  Otherwise OK, though maybe a little overpowered for what I typically use it for.
- Canon 580EX: Also too big. Can dial down the power, but no auto mode, and GN calculations are getting to be a drag.

**Edit**: for context on 'small' both of these are similar in size to one of my usual cameras, the Zeiss ZI: 138 x 78 x 32 mm (5.4”x3.1”x1.3”).  I'm willing to lose a lot of power to find a decent flash that isn't the size of my camera.

Comment: I know you discounted the Sunpak 383, but it seems to be one of the smaller ones...

Comment: Remember to check trigger voltages before using exotic flashes :-)

Comment: So, did you pick something up? I'm curious.

Comment: @John - I'm going to check out the Metz's this weekend. Pretty safe to bet I'll come home with the 20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at the Sunpak lineup? Some are TTL, but I think they have non-TTL and you can often find them on Craigslist.

To add from my comment, a very popular one appears to be the Sunpak 383 Super which is non-TTL. It's discontinued, but appears to be available on places like EBay. Anyways, BH lists the dimensions as 4.4 X 3 X 2.8" (WxHxD).

Another, similar, would be the Metz 36 Series C-2. Dimensions for that is 2.80 x 4.3 x 3.4", so a little bigger on some dimensions. The Metz 20 C-2 is 2.55 x 3.85 x 2.12", so small.

By the way, I'm not finding much smaller without going to the LED ones. They are an option as well.

Comment: you've basically just restated the problem. :-)  There's *tons* of flashes around on the used market, many of which use auto, but I have no idea how to sort the wheat from the chaff without compiling an encyclopedia.

Comment: @Matt - I added the 383, which I know you discounted, but also added the Metz.

Comment: the Metz 20 looks promising. It and the 36 are both available locally, too, which makes them easy to try/handle. Thanks!

Comment: @Matt, no problem. I can say that the Metz gear seems to be pretty solid, I have their ring flash and I really like it. Anyways, good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a SunPak 383, and it's a great flash, though I haven't had much luck in Auto mode since I switched to my DSLR.

Comment: Thanks; I appreciate the personal recommendation, but that one's about the same size as the Vivitar/Canon that I have.